# unix script triggered from putty

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have triggered a Unix script which is basically put details from DB and create a xml for many id's(approximately 1000 items). After generating all XML it will post it to a queue. Right now I have doubt. My Script is running in a script. I am just monitoring it using PUTTY. will my script continuing executing if I shut down my system?

Comment: Run it in the background with `nohup`, so it won't be killed when you logout. Even better, use `screen` so you can disconnect from the terminal session, and later reconnect to it.

Answer (score 0):

As Barmar's comment suggests, you should first start a `screen` session by typing `screen` in the shell.

Next, you should start your script.

Finally, you should disconnect your screen session and log out, with `Control-a, d`.

Whenever you login again, if you want to see the progress, you can do `screen -a` to reattach the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you executed your script in the foreground (or forked it to the background with `&`), it will terminate once your session closes.

To avoid this, you have a few alternatives:

- Use `nohup` with `&` to force the program to ignore the `SIGHUP` signal.
- Use a scheduler like `cron`, `at`, or your init system to schedule the process to run at/for a certain amount of time.
- Use a virtual terminal multiplexer like GNU `screen` or `tmux` to run the program in the "background" on a resumable terminal.

Using a scheduler is probably the most versatile of the three, but a multiplexer can be useful if you'd like to see the script's output in real time.